# Form with Save and Delete buttons

Tags: html, forms

I have an HTML5 form in a table. The last row contains two submit buttons, on to 'Save Edits' (to modify the record on the server) and one to 'Delete' (to delete the record on the server). This work well for my UI, but it has two undesirable side effects:

- When the Delete button is pressed, the data in the form is sent with it. I ignore it on the server, but it seems like a waste of data.
- The Delete button doesn't work properly if the data in the form fails to pass HTML5 validation (such as `<input type="email" />`). I do wish to keep this validation for the 'Save Edits' button so `novalidate` is not a solution.

Here is the code for my submit buttons:

```
<form action="" method="post"><table>
    <tr><th><label for="input-email">Email</label></th><td><input name="email" id="input-email" value="john.doe@example.com" type="email" /></td></tr>
    <!-- Other input fields -->
    <tr><td colspan="2">
        <div style="float:right;width:50%"><input type="submit" name="save" value="Save Edits" /></div>
        <div style="width:50%"><input type="submit" name="delete" value="Delete" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure?')" /></div>
    </td></tr>
</table></form>
```

I would like to avoid using Javascript if possible.

How can I fix the Delete button?

Comment: Maybe `<button type="reset">` could help you? Then the button is a reset button (resets the form-data to its initial values)

Comment: @theoretisch Maybe. Can it send a POST request with the `delete=Delete` value?

Comment: Hmm no I don't think so. It only resets the data. But I am not sure. With js or ajax that should be possible, but you wont use that if I understand you right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well,
for the delete button, you can use two approches,

1. You can use an ajax call with the only details you need for deleting the data. this way the page will not post back to the server, only the delete operation is performed. you will have to handle the removal part from the display using js though.
2. You can use a script for the onclick event of delete button, there you can ask the confirmation as you are doing now, then if the user confirms you can add the 'novalidate' attribute to the fields and then submit the form. this way the validation will be in place for the save, and for delete you can byepass them.

Hope this helps, let me know if you need further assists.